# Pass State Input into a new Step Function Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a simple function like below :

[image: Visual Editor for Step Functions]

This is just an example there will be other steps before the StartExecution step.
My question is, how do I pass the entire State Input from the current Step Function to this other Step Function execution?

I only see this option but looks like I have to do this manually.

[image: Visual Editor Step Function Start Execution Input]

Thanks!